# Linear regression, getting probabilities for different outcomes

Tags: regression, linear

I ran a linear regression (i got standard error as well)

it has the form of y= a+b*x

if i plug in 30 for x I get y=5

The question is, what is the probability given x that y is at least 2.

I have my mean 5, my se= 1.5 my df=20 and value of 2 THE SS is 7

Is it as simply as calculating the corresponding t value

```
t=5-2/se and then look up which probability that comes out to ?
```

Comment: This question, as you have phrased it, does not have enough information to be answerable, because for it to make any sense you need to assume a prior probability for the "result" (by which, presumably, you mean the expectation of the response associated with the number you plugged in).  You could then use the data to update that prior to produce a posterior probability distribution for the result.  However, there are other possible interpretations.  For instance, if "result" means "some independent future observation," then the answer would be totally different.  Please explain what you mean.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure if I understand your answer, but thank you. I did run a linear regression on data and got my value for the intercept and the slope. I plugged in a number for the variable  a+b*x (i plugged in x) and got the result of 5.  Now my question is , if i assume a normal distribution, what is the probability that with the same x i get at least 2.

Comment: The problem is that you don't know the parameters of that Normal distribution--you can only estimate them from the data.  The sense in which you mean "probability" is unclear, too.  After all, if you did your arithmetic correctly, then every time you plug in the same $x$ you had better still get the same result of $5$!  So, to make progress, perhaps you could edit your post to explain how we are intended to think of your result of "5" as being random.

Comment: Hope i helped :(

Comment: Thank you for trying, but you haven't addressed the concerns I have raised.  It begins to look like you might be attempting some kind of textbook exercise or homework problem.  If that's the case, could you reproduce the problem statement *verbatim*? If it's not, could you provide some context for this question to help us understand what you are trying to figure out?

Comment: The only piece of missing information is the standard error of the residual. With this info you obtain a standard deviation of the prediction and form a normal distribution around the predicted $Y$ for a given $X$ and use normal scores to find a probability.

Comment: I added the SS from the ANOVA table

Comment: All the three main pieces in ANOVA (Total, Regression, and Error) are expressed in sum of squares (SS), so SS = 7 really does not help. If you have the question post the question, if you have the actual output please post the output.